# Programatically get current version of ruby standard library

Tags: ruby

I looking for a way in my ruby program to determine the version of Ruby that is running my program as well as the version of the Standard Libary?

Comment: The `RUBY_VERSION` constant?

Comment: What about the Standard Library though ?

Comment: The Standard Library has no particular version. It's always presumed to be the same as the MRI Ruby version, though in the case of JRuby it may differ.

Comment: Can Ruby be installed without the standard lib?  We want to raise an error if the Standard Lib is NOT available because the Standard Lib is a pre-requisite before starting our application.

Comment: @grbonk As of right now it is impossible to install ruby without the stdlib. There have been talks of gemifying it, but those have not yet happened.

Comment: @grbonk, depends on ruby distribution. In general it should install with all standard libraries but for example in an RPM distribution, some might be missing. No idea how to check though.

Comment: FYI, on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 I see default gems installed in `/usr/share/ruby/`

Answer (score 0):

The version of Ruby is stored in the `RUBY_VERSION` global constant.

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

You can compare versions by using classes provided by Rubygems:

```
min_ruby_version = Gem::Requirement.new(">=2.2.0")
current_ruby_version = Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION)

# check if ruby conforms to version req using =~ operator
if min_ruby_version =~ current_ruby_version
  do_this
else
  do_that
end
```